# How to see what php scripts are running with top or ps aux

Tags: php, php-fpm

Is there a command that I can run that would expose what scripting is showing a php process in `top` or `ps aux`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're  using `php-fpm`, I only see a couple of ways to see what it's doing/done.

**php-fpm Status page**
You'll have to configure the php-fpm status page with the `pm.status_path` directive, as outlined in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php).

Then you'd need to tell your web server to pass whatever path you used in `pm.status_path` to php-fpm. That method will depend entirely on the web server.

Once that's done, you'd access the php-fpm status page and use the `full` query parameter to show all the workers (`http://servername/status-phpfpm?full`, if you setup `pm.status_path` as `status-phpfpm`).

That said, this won't show you the full history of what scripts have run, just what each worker last ran or is currently running.

**Web Server logs**
Check the access logs for your web server.

They'll show you what has run, and if all your PHP is in given directory, or ends with a `.php` extension, it should be fairly easy to find using `grep`. Depending on your document root, aliases, URL rewrites and other web server configurations, you might have to do a little bit of interpretation from those logs to find the full file system path of a given script though.

This method won't show you what's *currently* running because, as far as I know, most web servers only write to their access logs *after* the request has finished and an HTTP reply has been sent. This is so that it can log the size and status code.

Answer (score 5):

Commands you can use:

```
pstree | grep php
ps aux | grep php
```

---

**pstree** - [pstree info](http://www.linfo.org/pstree.html)

**ps** - [ps info](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ps.htm)

The "aux" switches show you:

- all the users' processes
- show you the process listed in a user oriented fashion (by user names)
- show you all processes, not just ones attached to a terminal. This will include processes such as services like crond, upowerd, etc.

**grep** -- [grep info](http://www.tecmint.com/12-practical-examples-of-linux-grep-command/)

Comment: It would be helpful to include some text about the commands...

Comment: Added some info about the commands.

Comment: This won't work since php-fpm doesn't show the script in `ps` or `pstree`.